# AutoHotKey: How do I disable a key for X amount of time after pressing it?

Tags: autohotkey

I want a script that will press a button once, and then wait 3 seconds, before allowing it to be pressed again in AutoHotKey.

I use F3 to send to send Q and {F3}.

```
$F3::
Send q
Send {F3}
return
```

However, I hold down F3 to send Q repeatedly, but I only want {F3} to be sent after waiting at least 3 seconds before it was last sent.

If you still don't understand:

(Holds F3)
Send q
Send F3
Send q
Send q
Send q
(3 seconds have passed)
Send F3
Send q
Send q

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remap the key for those 3 seconds to only send q, then re-enable it. You can do this with `Hotkey, *F3, off`. Look [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

Here is what you want F3 to do:

**F3 Mode 1**

1. Remap F3 to q
2. Sleep for 3 seconds
3. Send F3
4. Reamap F3 to **F3 Mode 1** (ie this same function)

Comment: from the question it seems he wants to disable it, meaning it can be "pressed" but without any action. if you sleep, you cannot do anything.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't what I wanted, when I hold down F3, it sends Q and {F3} and loops until F3 is released... However, when I hold down F3, I only want it to send {F3} a maximum of once every 3 seconds.

Comment: @Mare Infinitus The sleep happens after the F3 key has been rebound. So a subsequent press of F3 should trigger whatever action F3 was remapped into. AHK processes key events and their corresponding actions asynchronously.

Comment: @user2786228 Yes, I misread your question, I have updated my answer. You can use the same basic idea. Instead of disabling F3, remap it to send q while you wait the 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't think what you (deleted?) above does what you have described you want. Further F3 keypresses will "accumulate", and eventually they can Send F3 more than once within a 3 sec. interval. Eg, if you press F3 at time 0, 2, F3 will be sent at time 3, 5.

Comment: Error... Line Text F3_Mode_1() Error: This line does not contain a recognized function... Was I suppose to change this in anyway to suit me?

Comment: I should probably mention I have next to no experience in AutoHotKey.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I haven't been able to test the code, I mainly wanted to illustrate the idea. The code should have some simple syntax errors that should be easy to fix, but I will go ahead and test it for you.

Comment: @ealfonso I don't understand your answer, could you please simply write the full code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing my first solution, but wasn't able to get it to work. It seems that the dynamic remapping doesn't get installed right away. Below is a simpler solution, which uses the time of the last F3 keypress. Note that since you are sending {F3}, you need to temporarily disable the F3 binding, or else it will fire the action again.

```
last_f3_time := 0

F3_Mode_1()
{
   global last_f3_time
   Send q
   now := A_TickCount

   if (now - last_f3_time > 3000)
   {
      last_f3_time := now
      Hotkey, F3, off
      Send {F3}
      Hotkey, F3, on
   }
   ;else{MsgBox, Too early! %now%}
}


F3::F3_Mode_1()
```